# Princial is null in service /oauth/authorize (http post in approveOrDeny) after confirm oauth2 approval flow

Tags: java, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using the spring security oauth2 approval page, which when i authorize a request is sent as a "post" to "/oauth/authorize" (method approveOrDeny from class AuthorizationEndpoint), however one of the parameters of this service is null, which would be "principal".

The spring oauth page, when i click in authorize
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/aCIKZ.jpg)

Does anybody knowns why this parameter (Principal principal) is null?

This is the spring method which has the principal null

```
    public View approveOrDeny(@RequestParam Map<String, String> approvalParameters, Map<String, ?> model,
            SessionStatus sessionStatus, Principal principal) {

        if (!(principal instanceof Authentication)) {
            sessionStatus.setComplete();
            throw new InsufficientAuthenticationException(
                    "User must be authenticated with Spring Security before authorizing an access token.");
        }

         ...
         ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem, i had a class that was extending DefaultRedirectResolver and in the overrided method resolveRedirect i was calling 
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext()

Just removindo SecurityContextHolder.clearContext() the principal came filled.